# Socket connection rerouting

Tags: windows, sockets, tcp

Most proxy servers perform the job of *forwarding* data to an appropriate "real" server. However, I am in the process of designing a distributed system in which when the "proxy" receives a TCP/IP socket connection, the remote system *actually* connects with a real server which the proxy nominates. All subsequent data flows from remote to the real server.

So is it possible to "forward" the socket connection request so that the remote system connects with the real server?

(I am assuming for the moment that nothing further can be done with the remote system. Ie the proxy can't respond to the connection by sending the IP address of the actual server and the remote connections with that. )

This will be under vanilla Windows (not Server), so can't use cunning stuff like TCPCP.

Answer (score 0):

I assume your "remote system" is the one that initiates connection attempts, i.e. client of the proxy.

If I get this right: when the "remote system" wants to connect somewhere, you want the "proxy server" to decide where the connection will *really* go ("real server"). When the decision is made, you don't want to involve the proxy server any further - the data of the connection should not pass the proxy, but go directly between the "remote system" and the "real server".

Problem is, if you want the connection to be truly *direct*, the "remote system" **must know the IP address** of of the "real server", and vice versa.

> (I am assuming for the moment that nothing further can be done with
>   the remote system. Ie the proxy can't respond to the connection by
>   sending the IP address of the actual server and the remote connections
>   with that. )

Like I said, not possible. Why is it a problem to have the "proxy" send back the actual IP address?

Is it security - you want to make sure the connection *really* goes where the proxy wanted? If that's the case, you don't have an option - you have to compromise. Either the proxy forwards all the data, and it knows where the data is going, or let the client connect itself, but you don't have control where it connects.

Most networking problems can be solved as long as you have complete control over the entire network. Here, for instance, you could involve routers on the path between the "remote system" and the "real client", to make sure the connection is direct and that it goes where the proxy wanted. But this is complex, and probably not an option in practice (since you may not have control over those routers).

A compromise may be to have several "relay servers" distributed around the network that will forward the connections instead of having the actual proxy server forward them. When a proxy makes a decision, it finds the best (closest) relay server, tells it about the connection, then orders the client to connect to the relay server, which makes sure the connection goes where the proxy intended it to go.

Comment: The reason I put the constraint on the remote client is that it is a piece of hardware, not a computer, and therefore may have a fixed connection policy in firmware which I may or may not be able to update. My question was "if that WERE the case, is there a way to solve this problem?" and you are saying "no". Which is useful info for me.

Part of the problem being solved is creating a distributed system so that we can scale the number of connections we handle. A traditional proxy becomes a data bottleneck and a single point of failure. We need better scalability and robustness in our system.

Comment: Well if you put the proxy close to the remote client (e.g. same LAN), it shouldn't be a problem. And I guess you'll be having multiple proxies (distributed, right?) so that shouldn't be a problem.

Comment: The remote clients are mobile devices (not phones, but they probably will talk GPRS on a private network), so it can't be LAN-local.

Answer (score 0):

There might be a way of doing this but you need to use a Windows driver to achieve it. I've not tried this when the connection comes from an IP other than localhost, but it might work.

Take a look at NetFilter SDK. There's a trial version which is fully functional up to 100000 TCP and UDP connections. The other possibility is to write a Windows driver yourself, but this is non-trivial.

http://www.netfiltersdk.com

Basically it works as follows:

1) You create a class which inherits from NF_EventHandler. In there you can provide your own implementation of methods like tcpConnectRequest to allow you to redirect TCP connections somewhere else.

2) You initialize the library with a call to nf_init. This provides the link between the driver and your proxy, as you provide an instance of your NF_EventHandler implementation to it.

There are also some example programs for you to see the redirection happening. For example, to redirect a connection on port 80 from process id 214 to 127.0.0.0:8081, you can run:

TcpRedirector.exe -p 80 -pid 214 -r 127.0.0.1:8081

For your proxy, this would be used as follows:

1) Connect from your client application to the proxy.

2) The connection request is intercepted by NetFilterSDK (tcpConnectRequest) and the connection endpoint is modified to connect to the server the proxy chooses. This is the crucial bit because your connection is coming from outside and this is the part that may not work.

Comment: Having thought a little more about this, my approach will not work. The NetFilter SDK API will only intercept TCP/UDP connection requests made from the machine where the driver resides. So, as you're connecting from outside the proxy, I doubt whether the connection could be modified. So you'd have to use a transparent proxy instead.

Answer (score -1):

Sounds like routing problem, one layer lower than TCP/IP;
You're actually looking for [ARP like proxy](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Proxy_ARP):
I'd say you need to manage ARP packets, chekcing the ARP requests:

**CLIENT -> WHOIS PROXY.MAC**
**PROXY -> PROXY.IP is SERVER.IP**

Then normal socket connection via TCP/IP from client to server.

Comment: I don't see how this has anything to do with ARP. ARP is for resolving the MAC addresses of *local* IP addresses. It's useless when you want to choose where a particular *internet* IP address goes to - this can be done by the router, without involving ARP.